# I want to append year of date in alias, is it possible? and how?

Tags: sql-server

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
u.Title,
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS     'January',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'December'
FROM
pidilite_feedback_app_dev_latest.dbo.visit v,   pidilite_feedback_app_dev_latest.dbo.user_master u
WHERE
 v.VISIT_DATE BETWEEN '2017-01-30 12:45:43.673' and '2017-05-24 12:45:43.673'
and u.ID = v.USER_ID
and v.VISIT_STATUS = 'submitted'
and u.delete_flag = 'F'
and v.delete_flag = 'F'
and v.DIVISION_CODE = '10'
GROUP BY v.USER_ID,  u.Title
```

where I want something like this

```
 SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS concat(YEAR(VISIT_DATE),'January'),
```

OR

```
 SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'February'+''+YEAR(VISIT_DATE),
```

But it is not working, need guidance, thank you

Comment: You can only do this using dynamic SQL.

Comment: how, stored procedure?

Comment: I think you can't, it's too complex. Althoug mysql permits some kind of dynamic execution (see prepare command), you have to "prepare" a query which involves not a simple function, but a select itself, and concate the results in another query. I think it doesn't worth the effort, since the query you already have has the advantage that is simpler.

Comment: SUM(CASE datepart(month,VISIT_DATE) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [YEAR(VISIT_DATE)+'January'],                                                                  is showing as it is..@Gordon Linoff

Comment: Thanks @RaulLuna

Comment: What does your table data look like and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: i want to append year to January and all months

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.